# Anonymous function to select variables and get unique values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a simple task which I would like to loop over many datasets (which have similar variable names). I know how to do it dplyr, but I need to convert it to base R in order to get it into an anonymous function.

For example (this not the real data I am working with): 
This is my dplyr approach:

```
mtcars %>% 
select(mpg, contains("cyl")) %>%
distinct()
```

However, when I throw this into an anonymous function: 
I get an error:  Error: No tidyselect variables were registered

```
mtcars %>% (function(x) subset(x, select=c(mpg, contains("cyl")))
```

Any ideas about how to solve this, and how to add distinct() to the function so that I only get unique values? Any and all suggestions are appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `contains` is not base R, nor is `%>%` ... and base R does not know what to do with your `mpg` here (unquoted)

Comment: `mtcars %>% (function(x) subset(x, select=c("mpg", grep("cyl", colnames(x), value=TRUE))))` works, though

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! How would I return only distinct values? @r2evans

Comment: `unique` works on frames